# Allow user to modify method from outside assembly?

Tags: c#

Basically, I'm trying to write a library to help people with entity management for their games in C# and I was wondering if there's any way for the user to add functionality (similar to an override except they won't be inheriting from the class) to a method without directly changing the .dll? I know in C++ some people use callbacks and I was wondering if there's anything similar in C#?

Comment: Well yes, there are delegates - your method could accept a delegate parameter. If you could give a more concrete example, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Why are you modifying the method?  It's a violation of the S.O.L.I.D. design principles.  Unless the class is sealed, you user can use extension methods.

Comment: @tdbeckett I believe the OP is referring to his own application.  Sure someone could write an extension method, but his application would never call it.

Comment: @JonSkeet One example is they create a "component" which is basically a class which can be "attached" to an Entity to add functionality. In the .dll I include a simple transform class as an example which just includes a Vector2 position, but what if the user wanted to add a rotation, scale, etc. ?

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's correct.

Comment: Well that sounds like you might want an interface, or a delegate... it's hard to tell just from that much description.

Answer (score 2):

One option (instead of *modifying a method*) it to use a the [MEF framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow users to *extend* your application.

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers to discover and use extensions with no configuration required. It also lets extension developers easily encapsulate code and avoid fragile hard dependencies. MEF not only allows extensions to be reused within applications, but across applications as well.